# Java deepclone an object without some properties

Tags: java

I have following classes

```
class A {
    private Long id
    private List<B> listB;
    private C c;
    ...
}

class B {
    private Long id
    private A a;
    private List<D> listD;
    ...
}

class C {
    private Long id
    private A a;
    ...
}

class D {
    private Long id
    private B b;
    ...
}
```

I need a copy of A, include all of it's properties except all id column.

I have 2 solutions:
1. Clone each object and set all of the ids null;
2. Make a constructor like this:

```
public A (A a){
    //copy all properties except id
    this.xxx = a.xxx;
    ...
}
```

But i need write so much code for this function, any one has some better method to implement this function?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Make those fields `transient` and copy via serialization?

Comment: clone() won't save you much coding compared to a copy constructor, since Object::clone produces a shallow copy of the object, and you claim to want a deep clone.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/cloning/

Comment: Favor copy constructors over cloning. Are you sure you can't use the primitive long instead of the object Long? This would simplify things a bit and provide better performance.

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying Deep cloning of the object particularly the one of type Class A where you have an instance variable of a container type, you have below two widely known ways:

1) You Serialize and Deserialize the object.

2) You traverse through each method and call clone explicitely.

For first implementation, you may mark the **id** fields as transient and that should solve your purpose.

For second approach, you may override the clone method in each class where you set the **id** field as 0/-1) and call super.clone()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/) , it's a powerful mapping library where you can configure all the fields exclusions for your specific class or nested class, without having to write all the getters/setters manually.
I personally use it for deep cloning jpa entities excluding ids or auditable fields.
Ex:

```
@Mapping(target="id",ignore=true")
EntityA cloneEntityAWithoutId(EntityA origin);
```

Mapstruct will generate for you the implementations using getters and setters of the EntityA, excluding the id field.
Obviously is a lot configurable, see the documentation I shared above.